# Why is "iff" used instead of "if" Xcode Docs

Tags: xcode

[image: iff]

Why does the documentation use "iff" instead of "if"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iff is used for if and only if statement.

Statement enclosed is going to executed if both condition must be true.

ie. either both are true or none.